# Windows C++ DLL with multiple inheritance pointing to wrong method when reference passed

Tags: c++, dll

I'm running into an issue with a pair of DLLs that use a common interface definition (test application to prove out a concept, so obviously not prod code here).  I have DLL1 that implements this class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) UnmanagedDLL1Class: public IUnmanagedDLL1Class, public IUnmanagedDLL2Events
{
public:

    // Inherited via IUnmanagedDLL1Class
    virtual int DoSomething1(int a, int b) override;
    virtual int DoSomethingWithHybrid(IHybridDLL1Class* c) override;
    virtual int DoSomethingWithUnmanagedDLL2(IUnmanagedDLL2Class* c) override;
    virtual void FireEventOnDLL1Interface(char* msg) override;
    // Inherited via IUnmanagedDLL2Events
    virtual void FireEvent2(char* msg) override;
    virtual void FireEventWithAReallyUniqueName(char* msg) override;
};
```

And DLL2 that implements this one:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) UnmanagedDLL2Class: public IUnmanagedDLL2Class
{
public:
    // Inherited via IUnmanagedDLL2Class
    virtual int DoSomething2(int a, int b) override;
    virtual int DoSomethingWithUnmanagedDLL1(IUnmanagedDLL1Class* c) override;
    virtual int DoSomethingWithHybrid(IHybridDLL1Class* c) override;
    virtual int FireEvent(int delay) override;
    int m_eventDelay=0;
};
```

The base interfaces I've defined in shared header files look like this:

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILD_IUNMANAGEDDLL2CLASS
#define DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL2CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL2CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace SharedTypes
{
    class IUnmanagedDLL1Class;
    class IHybridDLL1Class;
    class IUnmanagedDLL2Events;

    class DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL2CLASS IUnmanagedDLL2Class
    {
    public:
        virtual int DoSomething2(int a, int b) = 0;
        virtual int DoSomethingWithUnmanagedDLL1(IUnmanagedDLL1Class* c) = 0;
        virtual int DoSomethingWithHybrid(IHybridDLL1Class* c) = 0;
        virtual int FireEvent(int delay) = 0;
        void RegisterDll2Events(IUnmanagedDLL2Events* pEvents) { m_pDll2Events = pEvents; }

        IUnmanagedDLL2Events* m_pDll2Events=NULL;
    };
}
```

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILD_IUNMANAGEDDLL1CLASS
#define DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL1CLASS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL1CLASS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace SharedTypes
{
    class IHybridDLL1Class;
    class IUnmanagedDLL2Class;
    class DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL1CLASS IUnmanagedDLL1Class
    {
    public:
        virtual int DoSomething1(int a, int b) = 0;
        virtual int DoSomethingWithHybrid(IHybridDLL1Class* c) = 0;
        virtual int DoSomethingWithUnmanagedDLL2(IUnmanagedDLL2Class* c) = 0;

        void RegisterHybrid(IHybridDLL1Class* pHybrid) { m_pHybrid = pHybrid; }
        void RegisterUnmanaged2(IUnmanagedDLL2Class* pDLL2) { m_pUnmanaged2 = pDLL2; }

        IHybridDLL1Class* m_pHybrid;  //unmanaged interface to hybrid1
        IUnmanagedDLL2Class* m_pUnmanaged2;

        virtual void FireEventOnDLL1Interface(char* msg) = 0;
    };
}
```

```
#pragma once

#ifdef BUILD_IUNMANAGEDDLL2EVENTS
#define DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL2EVENTS __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL2EVENTS __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

namespace SharedTypes
{
    class DECLSPEC_IUNMANAGEDDLL2EVENTS IUnmanagedDLL2Events
    {
    public:
        virtual void FireEvent2(char* msg) = 0;
        virtual void FireEventWithAReallyUniqueName(char* msg) = 0;

        void NotPureVirtual(char* msg) { int a = 0; }
    };
}
```

DLL1 and DLL2 don't link against each other, but both include the shared header files to define the common interfaces.  I have a third library that links against both DLL1 and DLL2 (using the lib files) and initializes them like this:

```
        m_unmanaged1 = new UnmanagedDLL1Class();
        m_unmanaged2 = new UnmanagedDLL2Class();
   
        m_unmanaged1->RegisterUnmanaged2(m_unmanaged2);        
        m_unmanaged2->RegisterDll2Events((IUnmanagedDLL2Events*)m_unmanaged1);
```

So the application passes each library a pointer to an object of the others' type based on the interface.  Where it falls apart is here:

```
int UnmanagedDLL2Class::FireEvent(int delay)
{
    //start thread
    m_eventDelay = delay;
    char msg[256];
    memset(msg, 0, 256);
    strcpy_s(msg, 256, "Hello from unmanaged DLL2");    
    m_pDll2Events->FireEvent2(msg);  //this fires the wrong method
    //m_pDll2Events->NotPureVirtual(msg);  //this works
    return 0;
}
```

In this implementation, I want to call a method on DLL1 from DLL2.  If I call a method I implement on the base class (NotPureVirtual) it works just fine.  If I call a method that is implemented on the first base class (interface) it works fine.  If I call something like FireEvent2 though, which is the second base of UnmanagedDLL1Class, the entry point in the debugger (I'm using VS2019) traces the call to DoSomething1, which is the first method in the first base class, not the second.  This seems to be consistent (FireEventWithAReallyUniqueName calls DoSomethingWithHybrid), even though the method signatures don't match at all.  I've tried a few things so far:

- I made sure that all the names are unique, so there shouldn't be any overloading issues.
- I sorted out the dllexport/dllimport declarations such that the defines are only exporting when the particular class is being built.
- I verified that if the implementation is on the base class, the call works.
- I tried changing the order of the base classes on UnmanagedDLL1Class.  Interestingly, this had no effect.  I loaded the DLL in Dependencies, and noted that the order of the exported methods remained the same in the DLL in both cases.

So given all of that, my question is, is there an explanation for why the wrong method is being called in this case, and is there a way to fix this, or is a DLL with multiple base classes like this just not supported in Windows?  I can refactor things into a single base if needed, but at this point I'm more interested in understanding why this is happening.

Comment: What is the declaration of `m_unmanaged1`?

Comment: It's declared as IUnmanagedDLL1Class*...  Although I newed it as UnmanagedDll1Class() and then explicitly cast it as IUnmanagedDLL2Events when I passed the pointer.  VS recognized the cast in intellisense, but obviously it didn't work. I changed it to be UnmanagedDLL1Class* and it worked though.

Answer (score 0):

@1201ProgramAlarm pointed out the error.  It turns out that I'd declared:

```
IUnmanagedDLL1Class* m_unmanaged1;
```

in the header, which means that even though I did this in the constructor:

```
m_unmanaged1 = new UnmanagedDLL1Class();
```

and explicitly cast the object when I passed it along:

```
m_unmanaged2->RegisterDll2Events((IUnmanagedDLL2Events*)m_unmanaged1);
```

It still mapped incorrectly.  I changed the original pointer to be of type UnmanagedDLL1Class and it worked as expected.  Thanks for the assist!